# Form groups in a list based on condition

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

(Edited based on feedbacks)

I've got a list like this:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,1,2,4,1,3,5,1,4,6,1,4,7]
```

That I'm struggling to turn into that:

```
result = [[1,2,3,1,2,4],[1,3,5],[1,4,6,1,4,7]]
```

I want to group my_list elements in sublists of 3 elements unless my_list[i] = my_list[i+3] in this case I want to merge those in bigger sublists.

Here is what I've tried:

```
result = []
for i in range(1,len(my_list),3):
    try:
        print(my_list[i],my_list[i+3])

        if my_list[i] == my_list[i+3]:
           result.extend(my_list[i-1:i+5])
    else:
        result.append(my_list[i-1:i+2])
```

Comment: Can you better explain the logic? The second and third sublists, share 2 elements at i+3, and yet they are separate. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that the result is correct?

Comment: "Here is what I've tried:" `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Please update your example

Comment: Yatu, Tom: sorry, there was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the description of your logic isn't quite clear. However, if I understand your code correctly, I think this is at least something in the correct direction:

```
def stepper(my_list, step, bigger_step):
    res = []
    idx = 0
    while idx <= len(my_list)-1:
        if idx + step > len(my_list)-1:
            # Remove this append if you don't want the "leftovers"
            res.append(my_list[idx:])
            break

        if my_list[idx] != my_list[idx+step]:
            res.append(my_list[idx:idx+step])
            idx += step
        else:
            res.append(my_list[idx:idx+bigger_step])
            idx += bigger_step

    return res

my_list = [1,2,3,1,2,4,1,3,5,1,3,6,1,2,7]
print(stepper(my_list, step=3, bigger_step=6)) # Output: [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 6], [1, 2, 7]]
```

Note that the above output is different from your given example, because of your given logic that you've provided makes the second sub-list extended as well as the first.

Using the above code, we can check the results if we change `bigger_step` easily with a for-loop:

```
for big in range(4, 10):
    print(f"Step: 3, Bigger_Step: {big}, Result:{stepper(my_list, step=3, bigger_step=big)}")
```

Output:

```
Step: 3, Bigger_Step: 4, Result:[[1, 2, 3, 1], [2, 4, 1], [3, 5, 1, 3], [6, 1, 2], [7]]
Step: 3, Bigger_Step: 5, Result:[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [5, 1, 3], [6, 1, 2], [7]]
Step: 3, Bigger_Step: 6, Result:[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 6], [1, 2, 7]]
Step: 3, Bigger_Step: 7, Result:[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1], [3, 5, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2], [7]]
Step: 3, Bigger_Step: 8, Result:[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3], [5, 1, 3], [6, 1, 2], [7]]
Step: 3, Bigger_Step: 9, Result:[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 7]]
```